# ASP.NET - Getting server local IP

Tags: asp.net, iis

I'm looking for a way to get the local IP of a server where the HTTP request was received on (ASP.NET with IIS).
For example, I have a server with multiple NICs (NICA and NICB) and an HTTP request was received from the client on NICB - can I know that it was received on B and not on A?
I guess that if there is way than it should be on the HTTPContext but couldn't find the right object/property.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
Request.ServerVariables["LOCAL_ADDR"]
```

This will return the server address on which the request came in, more about all Server Variables can be found in [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524602.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Try this using below code

```
   Request.ServerVariables["LOCAL_ADDR"];
```

Returns the server address on which the request came in. This is important on computers where there can be multiple IP addresses bound to the computer, and you want to find out which address the request used.

Comment: This is for retrieving client ip address. The question was how to discover on which server's IP address the request came.

Comment: NOw my comment is not relevant any more :-)